# Avoid whitespace and display error message in a textbox using c# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, whitespace

I have a `TextBox` and save button. The `Textbox` is set for only numbers, has to enter minimum of 3 numbers and up to only 4 digits. I need to make it such that when entered all or even one whitespace in the box, I need to display an error message. In the current code, I have set the error message to be displayed when entered 2 digits. But the `mtuValue` is an int property. I need an if statement to avoid and display `whitespace`.The code is as below. This current code for whatever set for now. So, all I need is an if statement for `whitespace`. Thanks so much in advance.

```
private ICommand MTUsavecommand_;
public ICommand MTUsavecommand
{
    get
    {
        if (null == MTUsavecommand_)
        {
            MTUsavecommand_ = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                if (mtuValue < 100)
                {
                    MtuMsg = "MTU value should be atleast 3 digits.";
                    MtuMsgVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
                    RouteManager?.DoMTU();
                    Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
                    MtuMsg = "MTU saved successfully. Service will be restarted.";
                    MtuMsgVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            });
        }
        return MTUsavecommand_;
    }
}

public int mtuValue
{
    get { return Configuration.MTU; }
    set
    {
        if (Configuration.MTU != value)
        {
            Configuration.MTU = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could always use .Trim() on the value to just remove the whitespace. Instead of throwing an error every time, or your could use int.TryParse() for the whitespace check.

Comment: could you please enter in my command and send?... much appreciated

Comment: What type of project is this? It seems to me that this type of validation should be handled on the `TextChanged` event, where the input is still a `string`.